# How can I avoid using the type name type

Tags: c++, qt, templates

I have a declaration in my base class:

```
template<class PROTOCOL>
static Packet* serialize(uint packetId, QVariantHash data = QVariantHash());
```

Then when I inherit from the base class, I can use the static method like so:

```
GameProtocol::serialize<GameProtocol>(0); // This works fine
```

My question is, what do I have to change in order to make the call `GameProtocol::serialize(0)` work (ie. without the template declaration).

I would like to keep the method static, as it simplifies other areas of the base class. I understand this makes it difficult as static methods cannot be overridden in C++, but there surely must be a way using template magic.

Comment: `GameProtocol` is the base class or derived class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `GameProtocol` happens to be your derived class: simply add a `static` method `serialize()` which forwards to the appropriate version of the base class:

```
class GameProtocol: public Protocol {
    // ...
public:
    static Packet* serialize(uint id,
        QVariantHash h = QVariantHash()) {
        return Protocol::serialize<GameProtocol>(id, h);
    }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Yep, this solution worked for me. Had to move the method in the base class from static to normal however since the compiler started complaining. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply write another function that wrap the template function in your GameProtocol class:

```
static Packet* serialize(int packetId, QVariantHash data = QVariantHash()) {
    return serialize<GameProtocol>( packetId, data );
}
```

now you can get rid of the template:

```
GameProtocol::serialize(0);
```